# Core dumped while accesing a variable (AVX2)

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, avx, avx2

Good morning,

I'm trying to solve a problem. I have two matrices (a & b) with size N = 8. I want to make the multiplication of them using famdd and broadcast.

The matrixes are declared like this :
`float *a = (float*) _mm_malloc(N*N*sizeof(float), 32);`

When I load the values of the matrix b into the variables (of type __m256) and I want to access to the values B1..B7, I get a core dumped error. While I can do it just fine for B0 !

Does anyone has an idea of the reason and how to correct it ?

Thank you in advance for any answer and help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 8) {

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 8) {

      for (int k = 0; k < N; k += 8) {

        B0 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j]);
        B1 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 1]);
        B2 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 2]);
        B3 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 3]);
        B4 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 4]);
        B5 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 5]);
        B6 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 6]);
        B7 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[(k * N) + j + 7]);

        printf("%f",B1[0]); //trying to access the variable B1
        printf("\n");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Most of your loads are misaligned (all but the first one). Use `_mm256_loadu_ps` instead of `_mm256_load_ps`.

Comment: @PaulR thank you it works. But what do you mean by misaligned ? how to correct that ?

Comment: [_mm256_load_ps - Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-intel-advanced-vector-extensions/intrinsics-for-load-and-store-operations-1/mm256-load-ps.html) the address must be 32-byte (256-bit) aligned_.  That means the address must be a multiple of 32.

Comment: Did you actually mean to load `B[x]` from `&b[(k+x) * N + j]`? Your first load already loads 8 elements from `(k*N) + j` to `(k*N) + j + 7`. Or did you mean to broadcast-load these values? (Using `_mm256_broadcast_ss`)

Comment: @chtz what I want to do is actually perform the matrix multiplication. I used the `_mm256_broadcast_ss` to broadcast the 1st matrix a like this (`_mm256_broadcast_ss(&a[i * N + k + 1]); _mm256_broadcast_ss(&a[i * N + k + 2]);` and so on) and then I wanted to load each line of the matrix b into vectors (that's why I created 8 variables B0..B7) and then use fmadd to do the multiplication